# Finest topology that makes a map continuous

Tags: general-topology

I'm studying general topology and a question has come to my mind.

I know that, given a surjective map (between sets) and a topology on its domain, among the topologies on the codomain that make the map continuous, there exists a finest one (in the course, we call it the quotient topology induced by the map and the domain-topology; its open sets are the subsets of the codomain whose preimages under the function are open in the domain-topology).

I wonder if there exists such a topology also for non-surjective maps, viz. given a map between sets and a topology on its domain, is it true that there exists a finest topology among the topologies on the codomain which make it continuous?

Comment: It sounds like you will want to put the discrete topology on the complement of the image of the map. The question is: What extra condition(s) on the map are required for this to give you a topological space?

Comment: Are you suggesting to start by considering open at least those sets whose preimage is open?

Comment: Just do the same and for $f\colon X\to Y$ define a topology on $Y$ such that $V\subseteq Y$ is open if and only if $f^{-1}(V)$ is open in $X$.

Comment: Okay, I can see that now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define topology $\mathcal{T}$ on $Y$ such that $V \subseteq Y$ is open if and only if $f^{-1} (V) \subseteq X$ is open. We claim that $\mathcal{T}$ is the finest topology on $Y$ such that $f$ is continuous. We can check these facts, which are overall quite trivial.

($\mathcal{T}$ is a topology) We have $f^{-1} (\emptyset) = \emptyset$ and $f^{-1} (Y) = X$, which are both open in $X$. Let $V_1$ and $V_2$ be open in $Y$. Then $f^{-1} (V_1)$ and $f^{-1} (V_2)$ are open in $X$. We have that $f^{-1} (V_1 \cap V_2) = f^{-1} (V_1) \cap f^{-1} (V_2)$ is open in $X$. Now, suppose $\{ V_\alpha \}$ is an arbitrary collection of sets open in $Y$. Then, $\{f^{-1} (V_\alpha)\}$ is a collection of open sets in $X$. We have that $f^{-1} \left( \bigcup_\alpha V_\alpha \right) = \bigcup_\alpha f^{-1} (V_\alpha)$ is open in $X$.

(For any topology $\mathcal{T}'$ on $Y$ with respect to which $f$ is continuous, $\mathcal{T}$ is finer than $\mathcal{T}'$) Let $V \in \mathcal{T}'$ be arbitrary. Since $f$ is continuous with respect to $(Y, \mathcal{T}')$, then $f^{-1} (V)$ is open in $X$. This implies of course that $V \in \mathcal{T}$, as desired.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that this topology gives the image of $X$ the quotient topology and makes every other point isolated (and is uniquely determined by this).